# Is it possible to go to the next post in the same category?

Tags: php, custom-post-types, functions, categories, permalinks

Is there someone who can help me to change the code so the button goes to the next post in the same category?

TaaaaannnnnXXXX

---

```
    <div class="nk-pagination nk-pagination-center">
        <div class="container">
            <?php if ($prev_post) : ?>
                <a class="nk-pagination-prev" href="<?php echo get_permalink($prev_post->ID); ?>">
                    <span class="pe-7s-angle-left"></span> <?php echo esc_html__('Vorig', 'snow'); ?>
                </a>
            <?php else : ?>
                <span class="nk-pagination-prev"></span>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($archive_url) : ?>
                <a class="nk-pagination-center" href="<?php echo esc_url($archive_url); ?>">
                    <span class="nk-icon-squares"></span>
                </a>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($next_post) : ?>
                <a class="nk-pagination-next" href="<?php echo get_permalink(next_post->ID); ?>">
                    <?php echo esc_html__('Volgend', 'snow'); ?> <span class="pe-7s-angle-right"></span>
                </a>
            <?php else : ?>
                <span class="nk-pagination-next"></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: when you say the next category, how are you determining that? E.g. if a post is currently in 3 categories which one would the next button be for? Are you trying to make it so that if you're looking at posts in a category and click on to the 2nd post, the next post leads to the 3rd? AKA you're trying to make where the next/previous links go depend on where the user came from?

Comment: Hoi Tom, maybe it is easier to exclude one category? Is that an option?

Comment: exclusions are some of the most expensive things you can do, rather than asking how to implement a solution to a problem, can you share the original problem that these are trying to solve for you? The problem is almost always easier to solve than the proposed solution, worst case scenario is it adds important context. This looks like an classic X Y problem

Comment: Tanx for your time Tom. It's a little to difficult to explain in English. But I give it a try. I have a few posts in differents categories. I only want to go to the next post in a specific category by clicking on the next button.

Comment: that didn't answer my question, it just restated what you originally said. Instead, if a post is in both category A, and B, should the next post be a post in A, or a post in B? _Why_ does it need to be in that specific category? And how do you know which category?